# What are the advantages or disadvantages of Owl?

Tags: tensorflow, numerical

Owl is the numerical library for OCaml: https://github.com/ryanrhymes/owl

It is supposed to be an equivalent of numpy and also have capabilities of tensorflow.
Any insights on why it should be used or why it shouldn't?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell it is promising but it lacks in multiple points.

The research below explains why it is better/worse than Numpy and Tensorflow:
http://pligor.tumblr.com/post/166198475026/owl-an-ocaml-numerical-library-research-by